# Telethon, client.iter_dialogs shows deleted dialogs

Tags: python, dialog, telegram, telethon

I have been using Telethon for quite some time with my own API credentials and phone number, however recently, I decided to log on my app with my brothers phone and notice something weird:

```py
from telethon import TelegramClient, events, utils
api_id = "something"
api_hash = "something"

client = TelegramClient('test', api_id, api_hash)

async def main():
    me = await client.get_me()

    print(me.stringify());

    async for dialog in client.iter_dialogs():
        print(dialog, "\n-----")


with client:
    client.loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

When I run the above code logged with my own phone number it will not show a deleter dialog. But if I ran with someone else's phone number, it will show the name of the deleted dialog.

Example: I create a dialog, ran the above example and log with my own phone, the dialog shows up. Then, I delete the dialog (using the official android app) and run the above script again, the dialog doens't shows up.
**However** if I repeat the above steps with someone else's phone number, the deleted dialog will show up.

NOTE: although the dialog show's up, the messages in the dialog don't.

Is this normal behaviour? What I am missing? Any comment will be of great help

====**EDIT**====

So, I have made some extra digging I discovered that this behaviour only applies to dialogs with **my** own account, aka, the account that owns the Telegram credentials.

Basically, I asked my brother to delete a group chat and when I ran the client.iter_dialogs, it was not there.
Then, I asked him to delete a dialog with another person, I ran client.iter_dialogs and the dialog was not there.

It seems that Telegram have some kind of exception just for the account that owns the credentials (maybe they understand that I will need to have it as way to communicate to my clients, maybe it's just a bug).

====**EDIT 2**====

So, I have run the script again... and now it's not happening. I have no idea what was happening nor why, but it has stopped showing up. Perhaps something at the Telegram API itself, but I can't be sure. Anyway, if, for any reason, it happens in your script post on this thread or open an issue back on [Telethon](https://github.com/LonamiWebs/Telethon).

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

add variable ***ignore_migrated = True*** to iter_dialogs()

```
async for dialog in client.iter_dialogs(ignore_migrated = True):
    print(dialog, "\n-----")
```

ignore_migrated (`bool`, optional):
Whether :tl:`Chat` that have `migrated_to` a :tl:`Channel`
should be included or not. By default all the chats in your
dialogs are returned, but setting this to `True` will hide
them in the same way official applications do.